# accessing properties of a class and printing them

Tags: ios, objective-c, theos, class-extensions

I have a header file like this:

```
@class NSMutableDictionary, NSString;

@interface randomclassname : NSObject
{
    unsigned long long _HTTPMethod;
    NSString *_path;
    unsigned long long _apiVersion;
    NSMutableDictionary *_parameters;
    NSMutableDictionary *_defaultParameters;

    NSMutableDictionary *_headers;
    _Bool _isSigned;
}
/// methods are down here
+ (id)builderWithHTTPMethod:(unsigned long long)arg1 path:(id)arg2;
```

I want to access and print `NSMutableDictionary *_defaultParameters;`

and

```
unsigned long long _apiVersion;
```

The follow properties inside my method object.

```
+ (id)builderWithHTTPMethod:(unsigned long long)arg1 format:(id)arg2 
{
    **access those properties here and print them on NSlog.**
    return %orig; 
}
```

Please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. I'm not entirely sure if stuff inside @interface are called properties; I'm guessing. But that's what I'm trying to access.

Comment: declare _defaultParameters as @property

Comment: What would the syntax look like

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add your `_defaultParameters`and your apiVersion as property in your .h file

```
@property NSMutableDictionary *defaultParameters;
@property (assign) unsigned long long _apiVersion;
```

after that you can cast in your method the param id as your randomclassname

```
+ (id)builderWithHTTPMethod:(unsigned long long)arg1 format:(id)arg2 
{
    //**access those properties here and print them on NSlog.**
    randomclassname *obj = (randomclassname*)arg2;
    NSLog(@"%@",obj.defaultParameters);
    return %orig; 
}
```

Comment: There are no others ways than setting the @property into my .h file? This is class-dumped h file, not sure if I can alter it.

Comment: can you show an example or even a psuedo code for it.

Comment: your builderWithHTTPMethod is inside of your class? @Dilli

Comment: I can share the header file with you. I renamed it to builderWithHTTPMethod https://pastebin.com/Ck1L8MSU builderWithHTTPmethod is called IGAPIRequestBuilder pastebin has the header file. @reinier-melian

Comment: @Dilli sorry but I can understand why you can't add those private variables as properties? can you explain a little more about of what are you need to do?

Comment: I'm trying to learn reverse engineering. Those headers files are class-dumped, not sure how I would go on about using the updated headers with instagram again. If you can show me an example of class extension with the pastebin I provided; that would help.

Comment: You are saying that you are decompiling and changing and after that compiling again? @Dilli

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165318/discussion-between-dilli-and-reinier-melian).